# Encoding strings with Sklearn pre-processing is giving an error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Im trying to use SK learn library and encode the strings so that i can run regression analysis and predict the winner but its giving me an error where the toss_winner encoding (see the image attached where toss winner is coded as 12 where competing teams are coded as 6 and 11 [Output Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBPc3.png))

Im using a public IPL dataset and a newbie in data science so need your help and appreciate simple answers to explain:)

Code used:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
encoder= preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
matchdf["Team1"]=encoder.fit_transform(matchdf["Team1"])
matchdf["Team2"]=encoder.fit_transform(matchdf["Team2"])
matchdf["match_winner"]=encoder.fit_transform(matchdf["match_winner"])
matchdf["Toss_Winner"]=encoder.fit_transform(matchdf["Toss_Winner"])
```

the intent is then to find the relation to the team 1 and team2 in other columns as below code and then Building, Training & Testing the Model

```
matchdf.loc[matchdf["match_winner"]==matchdf["Team1"],"Team1_winning"]=1
matchdf.loc[matchdf["match_winner"]!=matchdf["Team1"],"Team1_winning"]=0

#outcome variable team1_toss_win as a value of team1 winning the toss
matchdf.loc[matchdf["Toss_Winner"]==matchdf["Team1"],"Team1_toss_winning"]=1
matchdf.loc[matchdf["Toss_Winner"]!=matchdf["Team1"],"Team1_toss_winning"]=0
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the expected behavior nor what is the obtained behavior. Can you show actual outputs of what you'd like and what you obtain? Showing the input content could be nice too

Comment: Hi @LucG i have attached a screenshot (output code). hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well your use of the `fit_transform` method of `LabelEncoder` as I thought that each `fit` would erase previously memorized labels. I can't say if its a bug or what.. Maybe your input has already the problem you exhibit, that is the match winner is already not in the list of participants? Maybe it is a ill formated string (with trailing spaces or something?)

So I propose to instead first fit the `LabelEncoder` with all possible labels then transform the columns:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
encoder= preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
team_values = matchdf[["Team1", "Team2"]].values.ravel()
unique_team_values =  pd.unique(team_values)
encoder.fit(team_values)
matchdf["Team1"]=encoder.transform(matchdf["Team1"].values)
matchdf["Team2"]=encoder.transform(matchdf["Team2"].values)
matchdf["match_winner"]=encoder.transform(matchdf["match_winner"].values)
matchdf["Toss_Winner"]=encoder.transform(matchdf["Toss_Winner"].values)
```